# How to add shadow effect to 2D fractals?

Tags: physics, 3d, fractals

My question is simple: how do you add a shadow effect (like the one in Kalles Fraktaler 2)? I have tried distance estimation, but have failed at creating it reliably. I would like a relatively fast method, but it doesn't have to be extremely accurate.

[image: Kalles Fraktaler render with shadow effect]

Comment: This looks a bit like we're looking at a 3d plot from above, which is based on the distance from the set, and has been shaded as if light is coming from a particular direction. If you take the gradient of this function (which you can estimate by sampling nearby points), it tells you the direction of the surface. The dot product of the gradient and light direction vector tells you how much to shade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good description of the theory, with pseudo-code, see [Arnaud Chéritat's wiki page on drawing the Mandelbrot set](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Echeritat/wiki-draw/index.php/Mandelbrot_set#Normal_map_effect).

The [implementation in Kalles Fraktaler 2](https://code.mathr.co.uk/kalles-fraktaler-2/blob/b10275b763e6b6dc512a0e04fe377baa463c4bd7:/fraktal_sft/fraktal_sft.cpp#l1065) has two methods for calculating a 2D vector it calls (`diffx`, `diffy`) (which I will abbreviate $(x,y)$ later):

- if derivatives have been calculated, it uses the components of the reciprocal of the directional (complex) distance estimate;
- otherwise they're the difference in smooth iteration count between neighbouring pixels in the horizontal and vertical directions (`w`,`h` will be 1 for final colouring pass when all pixels have been evaluated).

Then the background colour is mixed with black or white according to a non-linearly scaled dot product of this vector with the light direction.

The parameters for the colouring are three real numbers `SlopeAngle`, `SlopePower` and `SlopeRatio`, which I will call $\theta$, $P$ and $R$ in the following, that modifies the input RGB $\mathbf{c}_i$ (calculated via other means, for example mapping iteration counts to colours, or via distance estimation) to give output RGB $\mathbf{c}_o$:

1. $$ d = P \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix} $$
2. $$ t = R \frac{\tan^{-1}(|d|)}{\pi / 2} $$
3. if $d > 0$, $$\mathbf{c}_o = (1 - t) \mathbf{c}_i$$
   if $d < 0$, $$\mathbf{c}_o = (1 - t) \mathbf{c}_i + t \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$